# Getting another search form result without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, html

User will enter product name in search box.  Based on the product name entered, I call a java script function to display price information in a table.  This is working perfectly fine.

When user enters another product name, price information of new product is getting appended twice to the same web page since i didn't remove the previous product price table.

If i refresh the page, table is getting cleared and i see only search box.

What i need to do to allow user to enter another product and get that result information table without refreshing the page.

Kindly help me out to resolve this.

My Code :

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf" id="cf-form">
  <input type="text" id="valbox" placeholder="Search here..." required>
  <button type="submit" id="butval">Search</button>
</form>
<table id="priceTable"></table>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pricecheckindia.com/compare.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="includes/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')
                $("#cf-form").on('submit',function(e)
                {
                e.preventDefault();
                var product=$('#valbox').val();
                alert($('#valbox').val());
                initComparison('mobile_phones',product,'saibrpwx','HGYMDNVKJGSPFQCP');
                });
        </script>
</script>
```

Comment: before you do anything, in form submit, set the html of your table to empty: `$('#priceTable').html('');`

Comment: @lolka_bolka : Wow! Thanks a lot it worked just like that.  Thanks again for your time and assitance